# combine 2 variable for select dropdown menu from WITH Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

Apology if my title confuses you. Here's my problem.

in my controller

```
public function create()
{
    $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');
            })
            ->with('profile')
            ->get()
            // What I'm trying to achieve is something like this. 
            ->pluck('profile.first_name', '&&', 'profile.first_name','id');

    return view('dashboard.documents.create', compact('users'));
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
->get()->pluck('profile.first_name', '&&', 'profile.first_name','id');
```

Form in blade

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('toUser') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('toUser', 'Select Borrower', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('toUser', $users, null, ('required' == 'required') ? ['placeholder' => '-- Select user --','class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required','id'=>'toUser'] : ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'toUser']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('toUser', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
```

Basically I want to see in the dropdown list that complete name of the user which is on the **PROFILE** eloquent.

what is the proper way to solve this? somebody told me to use **Collection** but i don't know how to apply that in my current situation?

Thank you much in advance!

Comment: so you want to get complete name, you have first name but I do not see anything like last name key

Comment: yes I want to get the complete name, first_name and last_name, which is located at PROFILE table.

Comment: how about using mutators it will create a new property called full name you can access it using `profile.full_name`

Comment: It returns null

Comment: how are you using it, should I post an example in the answer column

Comment: $users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                    $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');
                })
                ->with('profile')
                ->get()->pluck('profile.full_name','id');

Comment: you can't pluck it from db, as it is not in db, create a model instance then access it see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your profile model add,

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

then access it using

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector')->orWhere('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');
            })
            ->with('profile')
            ->get();
$profile_fullname = $users->profile->full_name;
```

I am assuming a hasone relationship of profile you can edit it accordingly.

Comment: profile.full_name actually works after I add  getFullNameAttribute() in my profile model. thanks a lot!!